# Formula to convert Bloomber ticker to ISIN, RIC or Factset ticker

Tags: finance, market-data, bloomberg, financial, reuters

I want to convert Bloomberg tickers (for equities) that to either of ISIN, CUSIP, RIC, Datastream code or Factset Ticker. I don't have access to Bloomberg but say if I just want to convert Bloomberg ticker to any other ticker as above, is there any formula or something that can help or has anyone ever done that before with using Bloomberg for conversion.

Comment: There is no such formula. See the Q&A "[How to map stock ticker symbols to ISIN](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/how-to-map-stock-ticker-symbols-to-isin-international-securities-identification?rq=1)" on another Stack Exchange for a bit more info.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's a duplicate. I find it a bit odd to ask for Bloomberg Tickets without access to Bloomberg. If you had access to Bloomberg you could simply retrieve all data like ISIN etc via their API. If you don't, it's probably not the best dataset to start with...

Comment: Bloomberg has a web site https://bsym.bloomberg.com/ allowing you (for free, with some limitations) to convert security id's.